# How do I include http headers with MediaPlayer setDataSource?

Tags: java, android, media-player, android-mediaplayer

I am passing a URI to the [setDataSource method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#setDataSource%28java.lang.String%29) of the MediaPlayer object.  I am targeting api version less than 14, so believe that I cannot use the new method that allows headers to be included.  How can I include headers (specifically, authentication header) with the MediaPlayer request and still support older Android devices?

My code looks like:

```
 mediaPlayer.setDataSource(url);
 mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
 mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

#### Background:

The method [setDataSource(Context context, Uri uri, Map<String, String> headers)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#setDataSource%28android.content.Context,%20android.net.Uri,%20java.util.Map%3Cjava.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%3E%29) has been included in the SDK (marked as @hide) for quite a long time (at least since Froyo 2.2.x, API Level 8), check out the change history:

[API Extension: Support for optionally specifying a map of extra request headers when specifying the uri of media data to be played](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/commit/256430093679e1d62b54fb0c852126e54d162f6f)

And has been unhidden and open to public since Ice Cream Sandwich 4.0.x, API Level 14:

[Unhide MediaPlayer's setDataSource method that takes optional http headers to be passed to the server](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/commit/72e738a428d7bb39a371da6105f7e2084e67e39d)

#### Workaround:

Prior to Ice Cream Sandwich 4.0.x, API Level 14, we can use reflection call this hide API:

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse(path);
Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
headers.put("key1", "value1");
headers.put("key2", "value2");
        
mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
// Use java reflection call the hide API:
Method method = mMediaPlayer.getClass().getMethod("setDataSource", new Class[] { Context.class, Uri.class, Map.class });
method.invoke(mMediaPlayer, new Object[] {this, uri, headers});
mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
mMediaPlayer.prepareAsync();

... ...
```

Comment: For pre 2.x versions of Android, I resorted to just passing query parameters with the url.

Comment: you save my life so late, i spent few month to find solution, anyway thank you

Comment: Is there any way to see the request url generated by setDataSource() after a request is sent ?