# How to add authorization header in android mediaplayer api version less than 14

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-source, google-tv

I have problem getting this to work as I need to pass a Authorization Header to my HTTPS stream, and since its a google tv application, the api level is not up to 14 to use setDataSource( context, uri, headers ). I tried out the method mentioned in this post [How do I include http headers with MediaPlayer setDataSource?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8959300/how-do-i-include-http-headers-with-mediaplayer-setdatasource) by using reflection. However, I get a error log like this:

[image: Log]

Any comment or help would be appreciated. Attaching a source code of an asynctask that i use to setDataSource. Please ignore the suppressLint("newAPI") line.

[image: SetDataSourceTask]

Comment: Error 77 means Problem with reading the SSL CA cert, I think your call to setDataSource is correct.

Comment: Why is there a BLOCKED output for the mediaplayer, and how can i ensure the SSL CA cert is read correctly? Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR - HTTPS not supported on Google TV's media player implementation

So here is the interesting thing about HTTPS and the media player on Google TV. For reasons I will not go into here the support for HTTPS in the Google TV media player was disabled - hence the "BLOCKED" - I know this might be frustrating to your effort - I am just the messenger. If you feel strongly about this I would encourage you to file a bug on the Google TV issue tracker.